# Two recent and (probably) working WD RED disks not detected by BIOS

Tags: hard-drive, bios, motherboard, power-supply, sata

I used to have a working NAS with the following four disks, all Western Digital Red :

- 2 4TB disks from 2013
- 1 4TB disk from 2019
- 1 4TB disk from 2021

[image]

The NAS was fully functional, and all disks worked when I stopped used them, about 3-4 months ago.

I'm now trying to re-use one in my desktop computer, so that it does not go to waste.

Obviously, I started plugging the one from 2021... Which didn't show up in the BIOS!

Then, I tried plugging the one from 2019... Didn't show up in the BIOS either !

Then, I tried the first one from 2013... And it showed up! Same for the second one from 2013...

I was using the same cables, on the same port of the motherboard/PSU.

What could explain this ? It seems to me highly unlikely that both the most recent drives died for no reason, when not plugged.

My motherboard is an ASUS Z170 PRO GAMING.

Thank you so much in advance!

UPDATE:

I tried to plug the disk from 2021 on a different computer, and it was detected and working without any problem (motherboard : ASUS P8Z77-V, even way older than the first computer) ! So the problem really seems to come from the motherboard.

What can explain that my ASUS Z170 PRO GAMING (from 2015) is not able to detect those two disks, whereare my ASUS P8Z77-V (from 2012) is able to detect them ? Can a BIOS configuration cause this ?

Comment: Have you at least checked if your disks are spinning up? You should check and document all the essential basics.

Answer (score 1):

I finally made it work : I suspect that my PSU was not powerful enough and/or that the power cable was damaged.

By unplugging the DVD player and using a different cable, suddenly the disks were being recognized...

Very strange, I guess the old disks needed slighly less power than the more recent ones.

Comment: Excellent catch! :-)